# Security measures for Laravel project (stolen database)

Tags: database, laravel, amazon-web-services, security

before explaining my problem, it is necessary to know that I am new in laravel, the problem I had was that the database of my project was stolen, when I tried to access the project, I could not, and doing a little research, when accessing the database I found the following:

To recover your lost database and avoid leaking it send us 0.1 bitcoin (btc) to our bitcoin address

I mention that the project server is in aws.

The problem solves it by restoring the database, but I would like to know what steps I can take to avoid a problem of this kind again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it happens because you ran your database with default port (3306) and using default root password (such as `'root'`).

There are bots around internet that will try to connect to *every* ip address on port 3306 with default password because it happens to forget this kind of configuration, when you are new to this kind of stuff.

There is no way to recover the database. Usually they make a backup, delete all the tables, and replace with a single table and a single row with that text.

*Please* don't pay those scammers, because they will be increase the chance they will continue this kind of operations.

Just take that as lesson for next time, protect with a strong password and maybe a non-default port for the database and make daily/hourly backups on another server